# Access Spree::CheckoutController#update method in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have created a controller say FooController which inherits from ApplicationController `class FooController < ApplicationController`.

I want to access `update` method of `Spree::CheckoutController` inside my FooController but when I do:

```
include Spree::CheckoutController
```

and call `update` method like:

```
Spree::CheckoutController.update
```

it says:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method "update" for Spree::CheckoutController:Class.
```

I am really new to ROR and Spree. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A controller method is actually a class *instance* method, you cannot access it from the class name. Doing a: `Spree::CheckoutController.update` is not correct. Please tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So i have this payment gateway integration where the actual payment happens at the gateway site. After the payment, merchant does a POST request to my site. After checking the POST request i would like to update the order so that the final order complete page will be shown which spree has already implemented.